# adding a value to a deeply nested object with arrays in it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the object:

```
{
  "status": {
    "affects": {
      "date_of_death": "date_of_death",
      "cause_of_death": {
        "affects": {
          "other_cause_of_death": "other_cause_of_death"
        },
        "value": "Other"
      }
    },
    "value": "Deceased"
  }
}
```

What I want to do is loop over this and add `{hide: true}`. But there are some rules:

- If the key does not have object as a value, take the value and make it into `{hide: true}`
- If it has `affects`, like cause of death does, add `hide: true` after value.

So the resulting object should be:

```
{
  "status": {
    "affects": {
      "date_of_death": {hide: true},
      "cause_of_death": {
        "affects": {
          "other_cause_of_death": {hide: true}
        },
        "value": "Other",
        "hide": true,
      }
    },
    "value": "Deceased"
  }
}
```

now this might seem easy, until you get something like this:

```
{
  "comorbidities": [
    {
      "affects": {
        "malignancy_type": {
          "affects": {
            "malignancy_type_other": "malignancy_type_other"
          },
          "value": "Other"
        }
      },
      "value": "malignancy"
    },
    {
      "affects": {
        "heritable_syndrome_type": "heritable_syndrome_type"
      },
      "value": "heritable syndrome"
    }
  ]
}
```

The exact same thing should happen here. Accept notice how its an array, This should do it recursively, deep diving into the affects, until no more can be found.

I have gotten this far:

```
export const createHiddenFields = (dependencies) => {
  let hiddenFields = {};

  if (dependencies === null) {
    return hiddenFields;
  }

  for (const key in dependencies) {
    if (dependencies[key].hasOwnProperty('affects')) {
      hiddenFields[key] =
    } else {

    }
  }

  return hiddenFields;
}
```

But I am lost as to how to finish this. I know I want it recursive, but I also want it fast, but still legible.

**Any Ideas?**

Comment: `status` has an `affects` key. Why doesn't it have `hide: true` after `"value": "Deceased"` in the output?

Comment: @adiga Great question, status is a field (a choice field in this case) and when you select a value, in this case `Deceaed` then we want to show the other fields: cause of death and date of death. If you then select other from cause of death we then show other cause of death.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using recursion and `for...in` loop and check if the value of the property is object then call the function again or if its not then add the value.

```js
const data = {"comorbidities":[{"affects":{"malignancy_type":{"affects":{"malignancy_type_other":"malignancy_type_other"},"value":"Other"}},"value":"malignancy"},{"affects":{"heritable_syndrome_type":"heritable_syndrome_type"},"value":"heritable syndrome"}]}

function update(obj, val) {
  for (let i in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') update(obj[i], val);
    else if ('affects' in obj) Object.assign(obj, val);
    else obj[i] = val
  }
}

update(data, {hide: true});
console.log(data)
```

Comment: [You shouldn't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572) though, so I'd expect an extra `if (Array.isArray(obj)) …` check

Comment: `else if ('affects' in obj) Object.assign(obj, val);` shouldn't be inside the loop. It just does the same hing for every iteration multiple times for no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for something like

```
export function createHiddenFields(dependencies) {
  if (Array.isArray(dependencies)) {
    return dependencies.map(createHiddenFields);
  }
  const hiddenFields = {
    hide: true,
  };
  if (typeof dependencies == 'object' && dependencies !== null) {
    for (const key in dependencies) {
      if (key == 'affects') {
        hiddenFields.affects = createHiddenFields(dependencies.affects);
      } else {
        hiddenFields[key] = dependencies[key];
      }
    }
  }
  return hiddenFields;
}
```

Comment: `typeof depencies` will never be an object... You mean `dependencies`, right? ;-)

Comment: @FZs Sure, thanks. I wouldn't have minded if you just edited my answer :-)

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, but people are usually careful about editing code in other's posts.

Comment: @TomášZato In obvious cases like this, one may be bold :-)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to post a late answer anyway, because I see some possible flaws and gotchas in the other answers. Specifically:

- `for ... in` is dangerous because it may loop over any iterable `Object.prototype` propertyes, which sometimes exist thanks to irresponsible developers. In general it loops over all properties including inherited ones
- `for ... in` is **not supposed** to be used for looping over an array
- It may be unwise to reuse the `{hide: true}` object. Should you later wish to alter the `hide` property for some entries in the tree, it would affect all that share the same object reference

So I'd instead write a longer but safer method:

```
function createHiddenFields(obj) {
  // ignore nulls
  if(obj == null) {
    return;
  }
  // For an array, just do the update for each object in array
  else if(obj instanceof Array) {
    for(const subObj of obj) {
      createHiddenFields(subObj);
    }
  }
  // For object, do the hidden field thing
  else if(typeof obj == "object") {
    // Replace all string values with hiddenVal
    for(const valueName of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)) {
      // Do not override value nodes
      if(valueName == "value") {
        continue;
      }
      else {
        // Process sub-objects
        if(typeof obj[valueName] == "object") {
          createHiddenFields(obj[valueName]);
        }
        // Replace primitive property values
        else {
          obj[valueName] = { hide: true };
        }
      }
    }
    // add hidden field for affects
    if(typeof obj.affects == "object") {
      obj.hide = true;
    }
  }
}
```

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Darker/b2trg6sv/21/)**